# Java code does not get called

Tags: java, loops, networking, stream

I've got a problem...
I have an InputStream by a socket and a FileOutputStream.

```
System.out.println("uploading...");
FileOutputStream fos = uploads.get(a); //Get the FileOutputStream from the HashMap...

byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFF];
for (int len; (len = s.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1;) {
     fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
System.out.println("test"); //not called
fos.flush(); 
fos.close(); 
s.close(); //not called
```

I have tried the copying with **Apache Commons-IO** too, but it didn't work too...

Do you have any idea? I think there is a mistake and I only can't see it...

Thanks Luca

Comment: Any exceptions? Add a runable example.

Comment: How did you manage to get a `HashMap` of streams?

Comment: At what point does the program stop? Do the control prints work?

Comment: No, there are no exceptions...

Comment: I have just put the Streams in a Hashmap with a Auth-Object...

Comment: Nope, there is no test in the Output...

Comment: Oh you should know the file is written to the disk... That works, but the code after that does not work... don't know why...

Comment: Probably the socket is not closed on the other side after the data is send so the `read(...)` method is blocking the `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks Titus! I didn't know that I have to close the socket on the other side to close it...

Comment: Yes, when you close the socket on the other side `read(...)` will return `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either Try/Catch or Throw that fos, so my guess is that you're throwing the exception, and then not handling it from the calling method. The reason your code below the for is not being executed is that after the exception is thrown, it immediately stops the current method, and returns to the calling method with the thrown exception.